# Filtering numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, filter

I have two numpy arrays (plot_x and plot_y) of the same length where plot_y is calculated based off on the values of plot_x. I want to filter the first array plot_x such that 0.1<=plot_x<=10 and filter the second array plot_y such that it contains the values that corresponds to the values in plot_x so that I can plot them in a graph. How do I do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your code? It might helps

Comment: first filter `plot_x` and later calculate `plot_y` using already filtered `plot_x`. OR you would have to keep it as pairs `(x from plot_x, y from plot_y)` to filter it aftre calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Filtering` the data using `Numpy-module` is one of the basic operation, one of the simplest way is :

**LOGIC :**
**1.** Define `Masking` Matrix which we will use to filter the data.

```
condn = np.logical_and(X<5, X>0)
```

**2.** Using `subscription operator []` we can access desired data with condition `masking-matrix` should follow `Broadcasting-Properties.`

```
X_u = X[condn]
Y_u = Y[condn]
```

**CODE :**

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([-1, -3, 1,-5, 2, 3,-6, 4, 5,-9, 6, 7, 8])
Y = np.array([i**3 for i in X])

condn = np.logical_and(X<5, X>0)
# for shortcut you can use => condn = (X<5) & (X>0)

X_u = X[condn]
Y_u = Y[condn]
print(X_u)
print(Y_u)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
[1 2 3 4]
[ 1  8 27 64]
```